# What is the purpose of Add & Norm layers in Transformers?

Tags: transformers

According to the article *[Attention Is All You Need](https://arxiv.org/abs/1706.03762)*, each sublayer in each one of the encoder and decoder layers is wrapped by a residual connection followed by layer normalization ("Add & Norm" in the following figure):

[image]

I more or less understand how the "Add & Norm" layers work, but what I don't understand is their *purpose*. Why are residual connections and layer normalization needed? What do they exactly do? Do they improve the model performances, and if so - how?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

*Add & Norm* are in fact two separate steps. The *add* step is a residual connection

[image: Residual connection diagram, described below.]

It means that we take sum together the output of a layer with the input $\mathcal{F}(\mathbf{x}) + \mathbf{x}$. The idea was introduced by [He et al (2005)](https://paperswithcode.com/method/resnet) with the ResNet model. [It is](https://towardsdatascience.com/understanding-and-visualizing-resnets-442284831be8) one of the solutions for [vanishing gradient problem](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/301285/what-is-vanishing-gradient).

The *norm* step is about [layer normalization](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/414219/cs231n-analogy-of-layer-normalization) ([Ba et al, 2016](https://paperswithcode.com/method/layer-normalization)), it is [another way of normalization](https://leimao.github.io/blog/Layer-Normalization/). TL;DR it is one of the many computational tricks to make life easier for training the model, hence improve the performance and training time.

You can find more details on the Transformer model in the great [The Annotated Transformer](http://nlp.seas.harvard.edu/2018/04/03/attention.html) blog post that explains the paper in-depth and illustrates it with code.

Comment: Solid answer; tl;dr: Add & Norm improves training, without making changes to the core of the model. Note that there are papers that change the style of the Norm (Eg: Power Norm instead of Layer Norm) to optimize performance further.